# Jackson XML Deserialization - Save an Unrecognized Field

Tags: java, xml, json, jackson

I am using Jackson to deserialize an XML file returned by a server. I'm getting an UnrecognizedPropertyException with the error message "Unrecognized field "" ".

The XML in question:

```
<Identifiers>
    <Identifier type="Organisational Study">Q2736g</Identifier>
    <Identifier type="NCT">NCT00109200</Identifier>
</Identifiers>
```

Stack Trace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "" (class sloan.scraper.Trial$Identifier), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: , "data2", "type", "data"])
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@28c2f254; line: 1, column: 547] (through reference chain: sloan.mit.cortellisScraper.Trial["Identifiers"]->sloan.mit.cortellisScraper.Identifier[""])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:79)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:579)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:672)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:906)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:328)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:147)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:18)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:375)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:107)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:308)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2796)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1942)
    at sloan.mit.cortellisScraper.Main.fetchJson(Main.java:173)
    at sloan.mit.cortellisScraper.Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

How can I use Jackson to save the unrecognized field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't save the unrecognized field simply because Jackson doesnt know where to map it to.

2 things:

1.) Check/Modify your object model and make sure it matches the XML.

2.) Annotate your class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` to prevent this error from occuring. The value for the unrecognized field will be lost, though.

Comment: Here is the output I get: [Type: null |Data: Q2736g, Type: NCT |Data: null]. Jackson recognizes where to put the "" field for the first item in the list, but not the second. It also loses the Type variable of the first item. My data model seems to be correct